# Opening second connection in nested transaction causes error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, transactions

```
using (Transactions.TransactionScope tx = new Transactions.TransactionScope()) {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING)) {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Officer1s Set isLocked='Y' where a='b'", conn); //refer to an nonexsiting name on purpose.
        var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        try {
            var a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            transaction.Rollback();//Invalid object name 'Officer1s'.
        }

        using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING)) {
            conn2.Open(); //throw exception
        }
    }
}
```

In my real application, the entry method is surrounded by TransactionScope. The entry method calls a lot of methods and is very deep. If in any connection the sql throws any SqlException (for demonstration, I refer to an nonexsiting name on purpose) and rollback the inner transaction, then I cannot open a second connection, because an exception will be thrown saying "The transaction has aborted."

Why is the outer transaction aborted? Is this kind of usage supported?

I'm using SQL server 2014.

Comment: Nested transactions in sql-server are a myth. An "outer" transaction does not nothing but increment the value of the transaction count. And a rollback will rollback the transaction and reset the counter to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The specific behavior you are getting can depend on various factors, such as whether you are using transaction pooling. In general, however, this is not the way transactions are meant to work.

Connections are expensive, so you would want to hold one connection open and use it over and over. A transaction exists within a connection, so it is not valid to use the same transaction object on another connection.

Judging by the sample, the code doesn't look like it's using nested transactions, but rather "nested connections", which is not the right way to go about this. What should happen is:

- connect

  - begin transaction

    - DML statement
    - DML statement ...
  - commit/rollback
  - begin transaction

    - DML statement ...
  - commit/rollback
- release connection

If you want, you can open two query sessions in SQL Server Mgmt Studio. In the first, execute BEGIN TRAN and then insert a row in a table. Now, without doing a COMMIT, switch to the other session and query the table. You won't see the row you just added (unless your ISOLATION LEVEL is *dirty read*; I hope not). This is the **isolation** property of transactions.

What should happen in the above code is, when the exception is caught and the transaction rolls back, the *transaction* object is done. The next logical unit of work begins with a new BeginTransaction().